# Each block bindings with nested Svelte components

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

According to [Svelte documentation](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/each-block-bindings), I can bind values to variables like this:

```
<script>
    let todos = [
        {done: true},
        {done: false}
    ]
</script>

{#each todos as todo}
    <input
        type="checkbox"
        bind:checked={todo.done}
    />
{/each}
```

Edit: You can create bindings for components nested within the `#each` block like this:

```
{#each todos as todo}
    <TodoItem 
       bind:done={todo.done} 
    />
{/each}
```

Don't forget the binding to the exported value in the `TodoItem` component.

Comment: You just *did* create a component binding, what is the problem?